# How to redirect contact form 7 to another page after submission?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to redirect to another page after contact form submission button is clicked but it doesn't work. I'm trying it following the oficial guide https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/ and putting this script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```

inside the additional preferences tab but it doesn't work. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this code and paste this into the functions.php file of your child themes

```
/**
 * Redirect user to hard coded link when form data is submitted.
 */
function contact_form_login_redirect() {
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function ( event ) {
            location = 'http://example.com/';
        }, false );
    </script>

    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'contact_form_login_redirect' );
```

I tryed and it's working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );
function redirect_cf7() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
if ( '947' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-1/';
} else if ( '1070' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
    location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-2/';
} else { // Sends submissions on all unaccounted for forms to the third thank you page
    location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-3/';
}
 }, false );
 </script>
 <?php
  }
```

Or you cvan you this plugin also 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/

Comment: Still doesn't work, and about the plugin, i think i need to do it by code. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `location = 'http://example.com/';` with `window.location.href= 'http://example.com/';`